# Python 3.5 efficient use of dictionary in simple greed nap sack algorithm

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dict of cows and their weight:

{'Betsy': 9, 'Oreo': 6, 'Herman': 7, 'Florence': 2, 'Maggie': 3, 'Moo Moo': 3, 'Milkshake': 2, 'Lola': 2, 'Millie': 5, 'Henrietta': 9}

I want to get a list of lists to move all cows, each nested list of cow's a total weight <= 10, hence to first two trips will have just Betsy and Henrietta: 
The Answer for GREEDY COW TRANSPORT:

[['Betsy'], ['Henrietta'], ['Herman', 'Maggie'], ['Oreo', 'Moo Moo'],    ['Millie', 'Florence', 'Milkshake'], ['Lola']]

Here is my code that took too long in a net grader:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows,limit=10):
    N = []
    for key in cows.keys():
        N.append((key, cows[key]))
    CowTupleList = sorted(N, key=lambda N: N[1], reverse = True)
    names = []
    for i in CowTupleList:
        names.append(i[0])

    Results = []
    while sum(cows.values()) > 0:
        result = []
        total = 0
        for cow in names:
            if cows[cow] != 0 and cows[cow] + total <=10:
                result.append(cow)
                total += cows[cow]
                cows[cow] = 0
        Results.append(result)
    return Results
```

Hopefully I'll post own answer before someone has time to respond

Comment: Perhaps this question would belong better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

thank you for all the help, finally came up with:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows,limit=10):
    '''cows is dict of {'name': weight, ...} pairs'''
    train = []
    while sum(cows.values()) > 0:
        cart = []
        total = 0
        for cow, value in sorted(cows.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True):
            if cows[cow] != 0 and value + total <= limit:
                cart.append(cow)
                total += value
                cows[cow] = 0
        train.append(cart)
    return train
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can make your `greedy_cow_transport` function significantly more efficient. It looks like you're reinventing several wheels here, not to mention some other weird problems with it. Ie:

1. Why do you declare the parameter `limit` but never use it?
2. Why are all of your variable names capitalized? Capital names in Python are typically reserved for classes.
3. Why are you creating the list `N` by appending one element at a time from `cows` to it?
4. For that matter, why aren't you using the `.items()` method on `cows`?
5. This one really confuses me. You used the `.keys()` function in one part of your code to get all of the keys, then stored them at part of a tuple in another list, then manually extracted out those keys again to put them in *another* list. Why not just grab them directly from `.keys()`?
6. Why are you reusing the variable name `N` in your lambda? That may be fine here, but it could easily lead to weird problems down the road.
7. What are you actually doing with the data? You declare and assign these variables, but never actually do anything with them. Did you mean to return them.
8. Furthermore, why is it necessary to get all of the names in a separate list? You already have that information in multiple places.

Putting this all together, your function may look something like:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows):
    cowList = list(sorted(cows.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return cowList
```

But then that just begs another question:

9. Why do you never use the `greedy_cow_transport` function? If you aren't using it, why did you include it in this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows,limit=10):
    train = []
    COWS = cows.copy()
    SortedCows = sorted(COWS.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
    while sum(COWS.values()):
        cart = []
        total = 0
        for cow, value in SortedCows:
            if COWS[cow] != 0 and value + total <= 10:
                cart.append(cow)
                total += value
            COWS[cow] = 0
    train.append(cart)

    return train
```

significant saving if you only call:

```
sorted(COWS.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
```

once, as apposed to every iteration of the 'for loop' in my original